# How to create div on page load after particular word or substring using indexes?

Tags: javascript

I want to create div after selected word or substring using javascript. I have a start and end indexes save in databases. So I am getting those indexes from DB finding exactly where to create div but its giving an error.

Below code I am using:

```
var pos1;

var start1,end1, range1;

function createNoteBox(element,st,en)
{
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var range1 = document.createRange();
    start1 = st;
    end1 = en;
    pos1 = 0;
    noteDig(element);
    // s.removeAllRanges();
    s1.addRange(range1);

  // var ra = n.getRangeAt(0);
  
  div.setAttribute('style','background-color:yellow;height:1.5rem;width:1.5rem;float:right;border:1px solid #f3a73b;position:relative; left:10%;');
  div.setAttribute('id', "" +st + en);
  div.setAttribute('class','newDiv');
  div.setAttribute('onclick','changeHeightWidthDiv("' + st + en + '")');
  div.setAttribute('onmouseleave', 'saveData("' + st  + ',' + en +'" , "'+ st + en +'") ');
   if (s1.rangeCount > 0) 
   {
       var range12 = s1.getRangeAt(0);
       range1.collapse(false);
       range1.insertNode(div);   //This line giving an error.Failed to execute 'insertNode' on 'Range': Only one element on document allowed.
   }
}
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: Failed to execute 'insertNode' on 'Range': Only one element on document allowed.